# Multi SQL Server Web licence on Single Machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have a cloud server on 1and1.com and that has 8 Socket/Core. I have aslo installed the SQL Server Web Edition provided by 1and1.com. At the the time of installing the options shows to me you need 2 licence (as Web edition is limited to 4 socket). They also telling, you have 2 licence and 2 licence distributed among  8 core and billed me for two licences. but it's look like our sql server is using only 4cpu.

When i run

> select scheduler_id, cpu_id, status, is_online 
>   from sys.dm_os_schedulers 
>   where status = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'

It is showing only 4 cpu is online. and rest four are offline when i run

> select scheduler_id, cpu_id, status, is_online 
>   from sys.dm_os_schedulers 
>   where status = 'VISIBLE OFFLINE'

Can anyone help me to understand with this situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing is a topic fraught with legal issues, advice should only be provided by the product manufacturer or possibly your lawyer.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the licensing question, there's a question about the technical limitations of Web/Standard edition.

Web edition is limited to "Lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores", but for a Virtual Machine the sockets and cores are reported by the hypervisor, and may differ from the underlying hardware.  That appears to be the case here, as the hypervisor is presenting the VM with 8 VCPUs and claiming that they are on 8 separate sockets.

SQL Server on startup looks at the reported sockets and cores when and will limit the schedulers accordingly.  Here that's limiting the CPU use to half of what it should be.

To fix this, the hoster should reconfigure the hypervisor to accurately report the socket and core count of the hypervisor host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to a licensing specialist to be sure, but I don't think that it works that way for web edition: each web edition license is associated with one instance of SQL server and each instance with one license so you can't give two licenses to one instance so that it can access more cores and memory. You could though instead two instances each with one of those licences, though unless your needs naturally separate out (i.e. you have a number of smaller databases rather than one or two large ones) this may be far from convenient.

https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/6/9C6EB70A-8D52-48F4-9F04-08970411B7A3/SQL_Server_2016_Licensing_Guide_EN_US.pdf states that the hard limit for web edition is 4 *sockets* or 16 *cores*. As you have a "cloud server" I assume this is through a virtualisation solution, perhaps this can be configures to make the CPU resources you have look like less sockets/chips with more cores (perhaps 2*4 or 4*2, instead of 8*1)? Though again, we really need a licensing expert to chime in (which his unlikely as their business model is usually more geared towards "you call us") as it can be a surprisingly complex area (and SQL Server's licensing is *simple* compared to some products out there!).

Comment: Interesting enough this is exactly how pretty much all per core licensing works with MS - you buy as many licenses as you need for the cores. Now, I will not bother reading up whether this applies to Web too - but it does or everything else, and MS really likes consistency, particularly in SPLAA (which is how this is ultimately licensed).

Comment: I thought it specifically didn't for web edition, though if someone has reference that says otherwise I'll happily stand corrected. Enterprise: per core (sold in 2 core packs), standard: per core (sold in 2 core packs) or per server plus CALs, developer: per user (but free). The main MS pages for SQL licensing say very for web edition little beyond "contact your hosting partner for details".

Comment: My reading of https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/6/9C6EB70A-8D52-48F4-9F04-08970411B7A3/SQL_Server_2016_Licensing_Guide_EN_US.pdf suggests that web edition has a hard limit of 4 cores or 16 sockets, and even with per-core license packs standard edition has a hard limit of 4 sockets or 24 cores (so to use more than 4 *sockets* enterprise edition would be needed).

Comment: SQL Server Web edition is only available through SPLA, and is licensed by the core.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/licensing-programs/spla-program.aspx For core-based licensing you must license all the cores on the server (or VCPUs on a VM), even if the edition you are running doesn't support that many cores. http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/6/9C6EB70A-8D52-48F4-9F04-08970411B7A3/SQL_Server_2016_Licensing_Guide_EN_US.pdf